# exe file won't run though I installed wine but can't install solidworks 16, any idea?

Tags: wine

I run the icon setup from a version i used to work on when i was using windows, I installed wine and another apps were installed but solidworks 16 isn't one of em!!

Comment: Have you checked on the WineDB to see if Solidworks is supported in any particular version of Wine?  There is often more information there on how to install, if that's the case -- and a lot of programs require special installation (winetricks used to install a certain dll, for instance) before they'll work.

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=318 so no, it won't work.